# Telegram SendPhoto() Methode in ASP.NET by Telegram Bot

Tags: asp.net, telegram-bot

I set the code for sending the photo to telegram, first is working on my localhost, after Update the telegram.bot package to ver 9.0.0 and publish to sever dosen't work at localhost and server.

i use the try/catch for sending Text instead of photo and now they not working, it is mean the Try block is working but it can't effect.

```
        if (offerListDetail != null)
    {
        StringBuilder botTextA2 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder botTextB2 = new StringBuilder();

        string remoteImgPath = offerListDetail.OFL_OfferImageUrl;
        Uri remoteImgPathUri = new Uri(remoteImgPath);
        string remoteImgPathWithoutQuery = remoteImgPathUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(remoteImgPathWithoutQuery);
        string localPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/telegram/"); //AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Images/telegram/" + fileName;
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFile(remoteImgPath, localPath + fileName);

        var botphoto = new FileToSend()
        {
            Content = OpenFile(localPath + fileName),
            Filename = fileName
        };

        //var botClient = new Telegram.Bot.Api("157612108:AAFr4y7WWT32xX41EMOVkmEW19pIgcHImv4"); // استانبولیار
        var botClient = new Telegram.Bot.Api("186221188:AAHrihjOH7__4vlF0DCNWLEzYQ3p3ORO0_k"); // ربات ری را
        try
        {
            botTextA2.AppendLine(" http://order.reera.ir/offers.aspx?offer=" + offerListDetail.OFL_ID);
            botTextA2.AppendLine(" " + offerListDetail.OFL_OfferName);
            botTextA2.AppendLine(" " + offerListDetail.brn_Name);
            botTextA2.AppendLine(" مهلت " + offerListDetail.remainday + " روز");
            botTextA2.AppendLine(" سفارش در http://order.reera.ir");
            botTextA2.AppendLine(" یا تلگرام @reerabrand");
            string botTextA = botTextA2.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n");

            botClient.SendPhoto("@istanbulyar", botphoto, "ddd");//botTextA);
            botClient.SendPhoto("@reera", botphoto, "ddd");//botTextA);
        }
        catch
        {
            botTextB2.AppendLine(offerListDetail.OFL_OfferImageUrl);
            botTextB2.AppendLine("*********************************");
            botTextB2.AppendLine("<b> حراجی " + offerListDetail.OFL_OfferName + "</b> ");
            botTextB2.AppendLine("<i> توسط وبسایت " + offerListDetail.brn_Name + "</i> ");
            botTextB2.AppendLine(" <b>مهلت خرید تا " + offerListDetail.remainday + " روز دیگر</b> ");
            botTextB2.AppendLine(" <a href='http://order.reera.ir/offers.aspx?offer=" + offerListDetail.OFL_ID + "'> مشاهده بوتیک </a> ");
            botTextB2.AppendLine("");
            botTextB2.AppendLine(" سفارش در http://order.reera.ir");
            botTextB2.AppendLine(" یا تلگرام @reerabrand");
            string botTextB = botTextB2.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n");

            botClient.SendTextMessage("@istanbulyar", botTextB, parseMode: ParseMode.Html);
            botClient.SendTextMessage("@reera", botTextB, disableNotification: true, parseMode: ParseMode.Html);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read picture with stream
example

```
 string pic = "نام عکس مورد نظر";
 string yourpath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Pic\"+pic;
 FileStream stream = new FileStream(yourpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
 FileToSend fs = new FileToSend("photo3.jpg",stream);
 bot.MakeRequestAsync(new SendPhoto(update.Message.Chat.Id, fs)).Wait();
```